# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory; Azure

Tags: android, microsoft-azure

Estou a tirar uma foto e depois quero enviar para o storage do azure no entanto na seguinte linha de código:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
```

Obtenho o seguinte erro: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory;

Alguém já teve este erro ou sabe solucionar?
Estou a tentar fazer isto em Android no Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o meu problema coloquando no gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

Comment: Vc pode marcar sua resposta como a resposta ideal. :)

Comment: Só o posso fazer amanhã, pois aparentemente não tenho pontuação que chegue. Mas obrigado, depois o farei